# Inserting a field back to same position in a bag

Tags: apache-pig

I am having an [inputfile.csv](http://pastebin.com/jbgPDNYP)
My aim is to split one field from Data bag and after some other processing I need to join them back to same position.
What I did so far is.

```
Data = load '$input' using PigStorage('$delimiter');
rankedoriginaldata = rank Data;
numericdata = foreach rankedoriginaldata generate $0,$split;
```

Run command

```
pig -x local -f seperator.pig -param input=data/StringNum.csv -param output=OUT/Numericfile -param delimiter="," -param split='$2'
```

[dump rankedoriginaldata](http://pastebin.com/cPj8Csxq)

[dump numericdata](http://pastebin.com/eSjazap8)

Above script splits $2 from Data bag and added to numericdata bag along with row id.Inorder to keeep an id for `joining` back.

1.From Data bag I need to exclude $split(ie eg: $2) and copy to another bag.

[Expected data or Duplicate data.(excluding $2)](http://pastebin.com/kq01HZPB)

2.I need to join back the numeric data to its excat position and get [inputdata](http://pastebin.com/jbgPDNYP) back as resultant.

How to do this.

Please Suggest a better way.